# Printing table values from specific web page

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I want to extract and print all the entries  for a specific month from the table

```
import os
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
import time

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

options = Options()
options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
options.add_argument('--start-maximized')
options.page_load_strategy = 'eager'

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)   
driver.get("https://www.sebi.gov.in/sebiweb/home/HomeAction.do?doListing=yes&sid=3&ssid=22&smid=18")

month = "Apr"
year = "2021"
```

How to print all the values from the table which matches specific month and year?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://www.sebi.gov.in/sebiweb/home/HomeAction.do?doListing=yes&sid=3&ssid=22&smid=18')

month = "Apr"
year = "2021"

for row in driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//table/tbody/tr/td[1]"):
    if month in row.text and year in row.text:
        x = row.find_element_by_xpath("./following-sibling::td")
        print(row.text, " ", x.text)
```

Prints:

```
Apr 29, 2021   Rane Brake Lining Ltd. - Post Buyback Public Announcement
Apr 06, 2021   Insecticides (India) Limited - Public Announcement
Apr 06, 2021   Jagran Prakashan Limited - Filing of Public Announcement
Apr 05, 2021   Sreeleathers Limited - Post Buyback Public Announcement
```

Of course, that only gets the results on the first page, you would need to incorporate pagination if you wanted more than that.

Answer (score 0):

First of all set the date range in filters. Then get the page source using `data = driver.page_source`

Next, use `bs4` to parse your data, `soup = BeautifulSoup(data)`
Next loop through  `for row in soup.select('div.table-scrollable tbody tr')`, `date = row.select('td')[0]` and `title = row.select('td')[1]`

Happy coding.